# Losing Session Variable After Form Submit in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm having an issue where my login form is losing the session data right after my form submission. Currently the session library is being autoloaded.  and I am using the CI_Sessions database to manage it. Here's my files.

My Login.php controller function

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('user_login', 'User_Login', 'required');
$validation_results = $this->form_validation->run();

if ( $validation_results !== false ):
    if( isset( $_POST ) ):
        $options = array (
            "salt" => $this->config->config['password_salt'],
            "cost" => $this->config->config['password_cost']
        );
        $hash = password_hash($_POST['user_password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT, $options);

        $this->load->library("users", "", "users_login_temp");
        $this->users_login_temp->get_object("user_login = '" . $_POST['user_login'] . "' AND user_pass = '" . $hash . "'" );

        if( !empty( $this->users_login_temp->id ) ):
            $_SESSION['user_name'] = $this->users_login_temp->name;
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $this->users_login_temp->id;
            $_SESSION['user_email'] = $this->users_login_temp->user_email;

            //redirect( "admin/users/list" );
        else:
            $this->load->view('login/head', $data);
            $this->load->view('login/body-login', $data);
            $this->load->view('login/foot', $data);
        endif;
    endif;
else:
    $this->load->view('login/head', $data);
    $this->load->view('login/body-login', $data);
    $this->load->view('login/foot', $data);
endif;
```

And here's my hook thats running on pre_controller

```
public function is_logged(){

    $path = parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], PHP_URL_PATH);
    $segment = explode('/', $path);

    $page = $segment[2];

    if( isset( $_SESSION['user_id'] ) ):
        if( isset( $_SESSION['user_name'] ) ):
            //echo "We found some user data";
        else:
            if( $page == "login" ):
                //be silent
            else:
                <!-- ALL SESSION DATA LOST HERE 
                   Session is present but variables are gone
                 -->
                //redirect( "admin/login" );
            endif;
        endif;
    else:
        if( $page == "login" ):
            //be silent
        else:
            redirect( "admin/login" );
        endif;
    endif;
}
```

if I print out the session variable under the login validation hook, it give me this.

```
array(1) {
["__ci_last_regenerate"]=>
int(1509199090)
}
```

**Amendment - My Session Config**

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = "ci_sessions";
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = TRUE;
$config['cookie_prefix']    = 'gm';
$config['cookie_domain']    = 'localhost'; <--This needed to be set to ''
$config['cookie_path']      = '/';
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;
```

Thanks in advance for any pointers or help

Comment: did you start the sesstion?

Comment: Have you set the session save path in config.php

Comment: Sorry I neglected to add a few vital pieces of the puzzle.  The session library is loaded using autoload, and the session save path is set to ci_sessions.

Comment: The only config item I question is `$config['cookie_domain']`. On my development setup (localhost) I use `$config['cookie_domain'] = '';` but on the "live" server `$config['cookie_domain'] = '.example.com';` is used. Try the empty string version. Also, double check that the table has all the right columns, etc.

Comment: Just did a test on my development setup using `$config['cookie_domain'] = 'localhost';`  Sessions fail to run correctly. Use and empty string `$config['cookie_domain'] = '';`

Comment: That was it! - Thanks for the awesome help.  If you edit your original answer I can accept it as an approved answer

Comment: check out the latest rev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the CI library `session` has not loaded when the pre-controller hook is called. And config/autoload.php has not been included yet either so "autoload" it isn't helpful. Until `session` can load the data associated with sessions cannot be accessed.

Looking closer, this first conditional

```
if( isset( $_SESSION['user_id'] ) ):
```

will never evaluate to TRUE because, unless you're doing something to start a session that you're not showing us, the `$_SESSION` super-global does not exist yet at the time the pre-controller hook is run.

You might be better off creating a `MY_Controller` class (extending CI_Controller) with this logic. The base is then extended to create all other controllers.

**Addendum:**
If you don't like the `MY_Controller` idea you should be able to use a hook but at a different point. The autoload.php file is included when the controller is created. So if you use the 'post_controller_constructor' hook point the session class should be ready to go and it should work.

The hook config looks like this:
File: **APPATH/config/hooks.php**

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'][] = array(
  'class' => '',
  'function' => 'is_logged',
  'filename' => 'post_controller_construct_hook.php',
  'filepath' => 'hooks'
);
```

Your hook function looks a bit more complicated than necessary. Perhaps you did that for testing purposes? Anyway, I'd suggest trying this version.

File: **APPATH/hooks/post_controller_construct_hook.php**

```
function is_logged()
{
    $CI = get_instance();
    if($CI->router->method !== 'login')
    {
        if((!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) OR (!isset($_SESSION['user_name'])))
        {
            redirect("admin/login");
        }
    }
}
```

The `router` class is will be available after the controller is constructed. But you have to get the instance of the controller to access `router` from the hook function. The requested "method" is easily found using the `$this->router->method` property. If `router->method` is not `login` it checks for the appropriate `$_SESSION` data and reacts accordingly. Otherwise, the hook does not have to do anything.

Last, but not least, sessions must be configured properly. That means setting the various config Session Variables appropriately for your chosen driver, but also making sure you have the Cookie Related Variables setup right too.

In your case try changing

```
$config['cookie_domain'] = 'localhost';
```

to

```
$config['cookie_domain'] = ''; //an empty string
```

Comment: Currently the session library is autoloaded.  So its getting started there.  Which makes sense now that you say it isn't loaded yet.  Is it bad practive to handle the session check via a hook?  So far it seems it's not a good method.

Comment: Bad practice? Probably a matter of opinion. Check out the **addendum** to the answer.

Comment: I tried using the `$RTR` variable but it came back as an undefined property. And that was after I switched the hook to utilize the `post_controller_constructor`

Comment: if i comment out the redirect inside `login.php` (which takes me to the admin) then the session data populates fine.  It's something to do with the `redirect()`.  I can print out the session array inside my validation hook.  When I enable it again, then boom, broken.

Comment: Re: $RTR undefined. Oops. Forgot that $RTR would not be in scope in the hook function. Check the revised addendum.

Comment: RE: redirect in login.php. The way I read it, if you remove `redirect( "admin/users/list" );` then the method goes nowhere - although the session data is set. At least that's the case in the code you show in the question. What does "broken" mean? That the session data isn't there or that $RTR is undefined? If the problem is no session data, then I put money on a `session` configuration problem.

Comment: Yes if I comment out the `redirect()` so it goes nowhere.  I'll hit the `login_validation` and it will print out session vars with my custom properties.  When I include the redirect and send it to the list it will still print out the session but there will be no custom properties like `user_name, user_id, and user_email`, they will have been lost.  I've tried using your latest amendment but to no avail.  Still loses the vars.

Comment: one last thing.  I completely removed the hook and let it redirect to the admin.  Still didn't have the session info.  So the problem is either inside the redirect itself, or inside my admin controller.

Comment: All you say point directly to incorrect config of the session class. This has been covered again and again here on SO. Do a little searching. You'll find the answer to the disappearing session data problem. It has nothing to do with the hook or the logic of your login.

Comment: Im already passed that point.  I searched for an entire day trying different things with no success.  Hence is why I'm posting here. I amended my session data to the original post if you can tell me where im going wrong with that.